# Call not thread-safe DLL function from Java's multi threads in parallel

Tags: java, c++, multithreading, dll

Although my C++ program is obviously NOT thread-safe, I need to call it from Java's multiple threads in parallel. I can not rewrite C++ code and need to execute DLL created by compiling the C++ program **in parallel** due to performance issue.

How do I call not thread safe C++ function from Java's multi-threads?

What I've tried is using JNA and call `Native#loadLibrary` every time when a thread calls DLL function. But, it does not solve the problem and occurs the segmentation fault.

```
public static class MyRunnable implements Runnable{
  ...
  public void run(){
    MyCLibrary INSTANCE = (MyCLibrary)Native.loadLibrary(MyCLibrary.JNA_LIBRARY_NAME, MyCLibrary.class);
    INSTANCE.cfunc()
  }  
  ...
}
```

I thought that new memory space for DLL is allocated by calling `Native#loadLibrary` and reentrant issue should be avoided. But, my thought might be fault.

I searched correct way to create multiple memory space for DLL from Java, but could not find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I call not thread safe C++ function from Java's multi-threads?

You can't.  You can't do it **because** the C++ function is not thread-safe<sup>1</sup>.

> I searched correct way to create multiple memory space for DLL from Java, but could not find it.

There isn't a way to do that.  (AFAIK)

Your options are:

- Restrict calls to the C++ function to a single Java thread ... or one thread at a time.  (Not acceptable, and in the latter case, possibly unsafe.)
- Launch multiple child processes to (each) run a C++ application that calls the function.  Pass the arguments and results via the process pipes or using network messages, RPC, etcetera.  (Problem is that the Java app <--> C++ app information passing could be a performance bottleneck.)
- Rewrite the C++ code to make it thread-safe.

The last approach will give you the best performance.

---

<sup>1 - This possibly overstates the case.  It may depend on *why* the C++ function is not thread-safe.  But if the issue is ... as I suspect ... that the function use static variable to hold state, then the situation is as I state.</sup>

Comment: Glad to get alternatives.  Thanks a lot.